# I am trying to encrypt a text by changing its character code and then converting it back into characters using python. but i am getting an error

Tags: python

I am trying to encrypt a text by changing its character code and then converting it back into characters using python. It is performing encryption but giving this error for decryption:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\CZ 3\Downloads\nis1.py", line 15, in

```
cipher1 = cipher1 + chr(ord(cipher[i])/2)
```

TypeError: integer argument expected, got float

```
cipher = ''
plaintext = ''
choice = ''
cipher1 = ''
a=''
choice = input("\nEnter 1 to Encrypt and decrypt ")
while choice == '1':
    plaintext = input("\nEnter the message to encrypt: ")

    for i in range(0, len(plaintext)):
       cipher = cipher + chr(ord(plaintext[i])*2)
    print ("encrypted text" + '\n\n' + cipher + '\n\n' )
    print("decrypted text:" + '\n\n')
    for i in range(0, len(plaintext)):
       cipher1 = cipher1 + chr(ord(cipher[i])/2)                        
    print (cipher1 + '\n\n')     
    cipher= ''
    choice = input("\nEnter 1 to Encrypt and decrypt: ")
```

Comment: What do you expect when the value is odd?

Comment: How can the value be odd? In encryption, I am multiplying it by 2

Comment: Then just call int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python 3 `/` is true division (see [PEP 238](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/)), it return float with two int:

```
>>> type(6/2)
<class 'float'>
```

If you sure all numbers are even you can use `//` floor div:

```
>>> type(6//2)
<class 'int'>
```

so try this:

```
cipher1 = cipher1 + chr(ord(cipher[i]) // 2)
```